# Supremum of a set to the power of -1

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

$$
A\subseteq(0,\infty)
$$
$$
\sup(A)=3, \\ \inf(A)=1 
$$
$$
B=\left\{a^{-1}:a\in A\right\}
$$

How would I go about formally proving that 1 is the supremum of B?

Comment: What means "formally proving the supremum of $B$" ?

Comment: $\frac 1x$ is continuous and $\searrow$ on $[1,3]$ so there is no issue here saying image is included into $[\frac 13,1]$, and $\inf A$ transformed into $\sup B$.

Comment: I assume you mean first computing the supremum of $B$ and then proving that it is indeed the supremum. before trying to prove it formally, can you guess what the supremum is? hint: what can we say about $1/x$ if $x>1$?

Comment: It is clear the OP must use the definitions of sup/inf to solve the problem. And you cant just say one transforms into the other...how is that rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are considering inverses of real numbers it should be clear that $1 = \inf(A) $would be a good choice for an upper bound for $B$. It is clear that the supremum will be positive since, for example, take the inverse of any element in $A \subset (0,\infty)$, then we must have that $\sup(B) >$ than that. To prove this is the least upper bound, suppose there was $0< x < 1$ $(\implies \frac{1}{x} > 1)$ such that $x > a^{-1}=\frac {1}{a}$ for all $a \in A$. But then $a > \frac{1}{x}$ so that $1  < \frac{1}{x} < a$ since $x$ is fixed, contradicting that $1$ is the infimum of $A$.